# Sum data and select the max value in PK

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here is my raw data:

```
+----+-------+-------+
| ID | Value | Group |
+----+-------+-------+
| 1  | 100   | A     |
+----+-------+-------+
| 2  | 300   | A     |
+----+-------+-------+
| 3  | 600   | A     |
+----+-------+-------+
| 4  | 500   | A     |
+----+-------+-------+
| 5  | 200   | B     |
+----+-------+-------+
| 6  | 300   | B     |
+----+-------+-------+
| 7  | 400   | B     |
+----+-------+-------+
| 8  | 500   | B     |
+----+-------+-------+
```

I would like to sum value column with grouping by Group column, but need to display the max value ID value in result.

This table is my as exception :

```
+----+-------+-------+
| ID | Value | Group |
+----+-------+-------+
| 4  | 1500  | A     |
+----+-------+-------+
| 8  | 1400  | B     |
+----+-------+-------+
```

I know it almost can be reached by

```
SELECT SUM(Value)
FROM table
Group by [Group]
```

But how can I also get the max ID in the group of [Group] column while SUM value column ?

Answer (score 2):

It's just a simple query as

```
SELECT MAX(ID) ID, SUM(Value) Value, [Group]
FROM T
GROUP BY [Group]
```

Comment: @Rick Read **[`What should I do when someone answers my question?`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)**